# Why did a div not show in another div?

Tags: html, css

I want to show a google map in this html div:

```
<div id="map">

</div>
 html,
        body,
        #map {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left:0;
            height:100%;
            width:100%;


        }
```

Everything is okay and it shows a google map fit to screen, and I want it to show on the other div like this:

```
<div style="z-index:1;" align="center">
       some thing this
</div>
```

But when I run my app, I just see the google map, how can I solve this? problem?thanks.

Comment: Put up a fiddle of what you are getting now. And try to give some example of what you want, as your question isn't very clear.

Answer (score 1):

The `z-index` property only applies to *positioned* elements (i.e. elements which have the `position` property set to something other than `static` (which is the default, and what the div is set to).

Comment: Position the element you want to set the div on by setting the position property to a different value.